# anyconnect installation not detected with Firefox + Ubuntu[13.04]

Tags: ubuntu, vpn

Details:

- I have successfully installed the oracle java 7 and browser plugin(works on other sites)
- I've successfully installed the anyconnect vpn client

Despite this, every time I try to connect, it asks me to manually install the anyconnect software.

[image]

^^ is what I get every time.

I've tried restarting, etc, never works.

Comment: Why would someone down vote this without an explanation?

Comment: Another coward downvotes for no reason and no other answer is given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like anyconnect web client won't run under linux/java 64.

Check out the source that is run during initialization:

```
function loadPackage ()
{
    if (IsLinux64)
    {
        ToggleHelpButtonEnable(true);
        // Magic state -70 == java applet weblaunch not supported, skip to manual download
        Start(-70);
    }
    else
    {
        // Magic state -60 == go to the next installed package
        Start(-60);
    }
}
```